# Run batch file using command button in MS-Access

Tags: batch-file

I have two batch files named as:

1) Combine.bat
2) Picenquiry.bat

The contents of Combine.bat file are as:

```bat
@echo off
for %%A in (*.txt) do (
  echo Processing file '%%A'

  FOR /F "delims=" %%L in (%%A) do (
    ECHO %%L%%A >> DataFile.txt
  )
)
```

and contents of Picenquiry.bat are as:

```bat
@echo off
ren "F:\meter_pictures\??????rc*." *.txt 
call "F:\meter_pictures\combine.bat"
```

I am using a button on form and following code is used for click on button:

```vbs
strReportpath = "F:\meter_pictures\"
Shell strReportpath & "Picenquiry.bat"
```

Unfortunately It runs but only run Picenquiry.bat file and do not run Combine.bat file as it is called in this batch file.

But when I run Picenquiry.bat file directly without using VBA i.e. by double clicking file name, it runs and make "DataFile.txt".

What mistake I am doing?

Comment: why are you calling the file? why not just do `"F:\meter_pictures\combine.bat"` or `start /b "" "F:\meter_pictures\combine.bat"`

Comment: Why even do that? Why not add `ren "??????rc*." *.txt` to the top of `Combine.bat` and change the button code to `Shell strReportpath & "Combine.bat"` instead!

Comment: Dear Gerhard I used "F:\meter_pictures\combine.bat" but same result came. I also add ren "??????rc*." *.txt to the top of combine.bat, but still converted to text file but "DataFile" is not created.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: If  you wish to notify @GerhardBarnard of a message, please use the appropriate `@` handle. Tab completion of names is available in comments.

Comment: @halfer Thanks! Wish everyone understood that use `@` handle actually informs the user.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I actually means that I'm working on a project which is going to be launch shortly. I didn't want to hurt anyone, we are all like a family members. Any how I'm extremely sorry.